# Optimize Get-WinEvent to run through entries faster

Tags: powershell, optimization, query-optimization

So I have this script that loops through the Windows Security log to check if there has been any activity on an account the last 7 days (because the retention on the log is 7 days - would be a bonus to get a day limiter into the script). However, each run takes about 6 hours (1,2mil events). The fact that listing them inside the event viewer only takes a couple of seconds makes me believe I can write the code more optimized. Any insight on this?

Code:

```
$startTime = (Get-Date)
$filter = @{LogName='Security';ProviderName='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing'}
$i = 0

$entries = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable $filter -ComputerName localhost | ForEach-Object{
    $eventXml = ([xml]$_.ToXml()).Event
    $userName = ($eventXml.EventData.Data | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'TargetUserName' }).'#text'
    $computer = ($eventXml.EventData.Data | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'WorkstationName'}).'#text'

    If($userName -match "Username1" -or $userName -match "Username2" -or $userName -match "Username3")
        {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Time     = [DateTime]$eventXml.System.TimeCreated.SystemTime
            UserName = $userName
            Computer = $computer
            }
        }
    $i++
    Write-Progress -activity "Scanning Win Events..." -status "Scanned: $i"
}
$filetime = Get-Date -Format "ddMMyyyyHHmm"
$entries | Out-File "C:\Temp\UsedAccounts$filetime.txt"
$endTime = (Get-Date)
'Duration: {0:mm} min {0:ss} sec' -f ($endTime-$startTime)
```

EDIT
After sugestions, the code now looks like this, unfortunatly with no major time improvements.
Note that a specific event ID did not change the exec time either, it still parses all entries.
Any more thoughts?

```
$startTime = (Get-Date)
$filter = @{
    LogName      ='Security'
    ProviderName ='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing'
    StartTime    = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).Date
}

$entries = foreach ($entry in (Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable $filter -ComputerName localhost)){
    $eventXml = ([xml]$entry.ToXml()).Event
    $userName = ($eventXml.EventData.Data | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'TargetUserName' }).'#text'
    $computer = ($eventXml.EventData.Data | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'WorkstationName' }).'#text'

    If($userName -match 'User1|User2|User3')
        {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Time     = [DateTime]$eventXml.System.TimeCreated.SystemTime
            UserName = $userName
            Computer = $computer
            }
        }
}
$filetime = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMddHHmm"
$entries | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\UsedAccounts$filetime.csv" -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
$endTime = (Get-Date)
'Duration: {0:hh}h {0:mm}min {0:ss}sec' -f ($endTime-$startTime)
```

Comment: Are you actually running this code against a remote computer? If the answer is "yes" you may try to run this code *locally* on the computer you want to query through `Invoke-Command`. This might speed up the code.

Comment: It's against the local machine (-ComputerName localhost), unnecessary code perhaps.

Comment: Hmmm .. that's strange ...

Comment: Just taking a stab here but since $Entries becomes an array of  CustomPSObjects is it a problem of PS having to re-create the array every time a new item is added? Maybe defining $Entries as an object with an add method would speed things up. Just a thought.

Comment: @RetiredGeek Usually that's just the case when you use the `+=` operation to add elements to an array.  ... what's not the case here.  ;-)

Comment: But since we try to avoid the pipeline if we're looking for speed you could try to use `foreach` loop instead.

Comment: Remove `Write-Progress` and save the results using `Export-Csv` because it's an array of **objects**, not simple strings. Also combining the usernames to match as `username1|username2|username3` could help speeding things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some heavy googling I've optimized the script to run in about 3min instead of 6 hours...
Apparently the -filterhashtable is known to be extremely slow, instead I'm using -filterxpath. Another benefit to that is the param -logname (that is not available with -filterhashtable) that cuts down the time the most since instead of filtering the entire log I'm only looking into the specific log I'm interested in.

Here is the final code:

```
$startTime = (Get-Date)
$XPath = "*[EventData[Data[@Name='TargetUserName'] and (Data='User1' or Data='User2' or Data='User3')] and System[TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) <= 86400000]]]"

$entries = foreach ($entry in (Get-WinEvent -LogName 'Security' -FilterXPath $XPath -ComputerName 'localhost')){
    $eventXml = ([xml]$entry.ToXml()).Event
    $userName = ($eventXml.EventData.Data | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'TargetUserName' }).'#text'
    $computer = ($eventXml.EventData.Data | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'WorkstationName' }).'#text'

        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Time     = [DateTime]$eventXml.System.TimeCreated.SystemTime
            UserName = $userName
            Computer = $computer
            }
}
$filetime = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMddHHmm"
$entries | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\UsedAccounts$filetime.csv" -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
$endTime = (Get-Date)
'Duration: {0:hh}h {0:mm}min {0:ss}sec' -f ($endTime-$startTime)
```

Answer (score 2):

As commented, there are some ways to speed things up:

1. Add an event id to the filter instead of asking for **all** event types. Also, not all events will have a `TargetUserName` item..
2. Change the `ForEach-Object` loop into a `foreach()` which is faster than piping
3. Do not write out stuff or `Write-Progress` inside the loop

```
# filter on logon, because not all events would have a 'TargetUserName' item..
$filter = @{LogName='Security';ProviderName='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing'; ID=4624}

$entries = foreach ($entry in (Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable $filter -ComputerName localhost)) {
    $eventXml = ([xml]$entry.ToXml()).Event
    $userName = ($eventXml.EventData.Data | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'TargetUserName' }).'#text'
    # if you need 'whole-word' matching, change to
    # $username -match '\b(Username1|Username2|Username3)\b'
    if($userName -match 'Username1|Username2|Username3') {
        $computer = ($eventXml.EventData.Data | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'WorkstationName'}).'#text'
        # output an object
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Time     = [DateTime]$eventXml.System.TimeCreated.SystemTime
            UserName = $userName
            Computer = $computer
        }
    }
    # don't waste time writing unnecessary stuff in the loop with
    # Write-Progress or Write-Host
}

# now output the objects to a structured Csv file you can
# double-click to open in Excel
$filetime = Get-Date -Format "ddMMyyyyHHmm"
$entries | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\UsedAccounts$filetime.csv" -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

---

Almost forgot..
You can limit the events to be from the last 7 days by extending the filter:

```
$filter = @{
    LogName      ='Security'
    ProviderName ='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing'
    ID           = 4624
    StartTime    = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7).Date
}
```

Comment: Great suggestions! I'm going to try them today and report back.

Btw, in this case do you usually mark the answer as "solved" even though it's an ongoing optimization?

Comment: @Salve, yes, please report back. Whether you 'need' to mark the answer accepted or not is of course up to you, but if this indeed solved your problem, it would help making it easier to find for others with a similar question.

Comment: I have updated the code, unfortunatly with no improvements to exec time.
Perhaps it's just how long the Get-WinEvent takes?

Comment: @Salve Yes, Get-WinEvent does take its time to get the events, but with the above you should really have seen speed improvement, Escecially by removing `Write-Progress`.. Are you running this locally or on a remote connection? Did you initialize your variable `$startTime` when the code starts? Did you add `StartTime    = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7).Date` to the $filter?

Comment: I've now cut down the time from 6h to 3min, see my own answer below. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Theo was faster than me, but in addition to his suggestions I would recommend using `-FilterXml` If you change to using XML for your filter instead of a hashtable you can definitely improve your filter options, including specifying how recent your results are.

```
$filter = @'
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Security">
    <Select Path="Security">*[System[TimeCreated[@SystemTime&gt;='2021-09-15T17:39:00.000Z']]]</Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
'@

$entries = Get-WinEvent -FilterXml $filter
```

That would get everything in the Security log from today at 10:39 AM to now. You could set that to whatever date/time you want. Is it fast? No, it really isn't. Loading 10 minutes of log data, just over 8200 entries for me, took 1 minute 18 seconds. Is it faster than grabbing the entire log? Oh heck yeah it is! I have not allowed it to load the 109k entries my system has (I have a 100MB limit on the file), but I imagine it would be proportionately longer.

Past that I would really consider just running a regex match against the message of the event rather than converting everything to XML. Admittedly, the bulk of your time is just getting the events into PowerShell, but processing them is going to take time too, and just running a regex match against the message rather than converting to XML and parsing that takes (on my dev box at least) 60x longer to convert to XML and parse that. Sure, that's just 30 milliseconds vs 1829, but that's to reduce 8.2k events down to 8. With 1.2 million that's going to become a bit more significant. Since this is always being run on the local machine you may as well just use `$env:COMPUTERNAME` rather than pull the computer name from each event. So here's what I would do after you get your event log entries:

```
$filtered=ForEach($entry in $entries){
    if($entry.Message -match "(?ms)Target Subject:.+?   Account Name:\s+(user1|user2|user3)"){
        [pscustomobject]@{
            TimeCreated=$entry.TimeCreated
            User=$Matches[1]
            Computer=$env:COMPUTERNAME
        }
    }
}
$filetime = Get-Date -Format "ddMMyyyyHHmm"
$filtered | Out-File "C:\Temp\UsedAccounts$filetime.txt"
```

Comment: Just to mention that the `Message` property is **localized**, so for every different culture, you would have to adapt the regex.

Comment: The reason it's convrted to XML is that it was much easier to find properties (and regex is a pain for me). I'm gonna try your suggestions today

Comment: Another note: the computer variable is rarely the same as the one running the script (ADDC), it's where the logon is from

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I've answered the question myself now if you're interested